# Using 'eachWithindex' groovy instead of For loops to read in json data

Tags: groovy

I'm having trouble with converting an existing FOR loop to use the 'eachWithIndex' groovy function.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this successfully, examples I've seen are quite straightforward on tutorials but I'm not sure how to make them work with groovy json files.

The current solution uses a For loop which reads in data from 3 different groovy files

```
 Add_Page1_data = data.get("json_Page1")
 Add_Page2_data = data.get("json_Page2")
 Add_Page3_data = data.get("json_Page3")

    for (int i=0; i< Add_Page1_data.size(); i++) {
        execute(w, Add_Page1_data[i],
                   Add_Page2_data[i],
                   Add_Page3_data[i])
    }
```

I then use the following code to populate data inside windows by accessing the page objects of the file before :

```
  def execute(w, data1) {
    def page1 = new PO_Add_Page1(wrapper: w)
    page1.typeInSomeText(data1.sometext) 
    }
```

PageObject file looks like this:

```
class PO_Add_Page1 {
def typeInSomeText(val) {
    wrapper.findWithLabel("Some Text  . .").rightEditable().type(val)
}
```

Json file used contains multiple records like this:

```
{
"json_Page1": [
    {
        "sometext": "text1"
    },
    {
        "sometext": "text2"
    },
```

The json is fed in as the "data" which maps to elements on the page using the page object groovy file.

I wanted to be able to repeat the same functionality in a more groovy idiomatic way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `[Add_Page1_data, Add_Page2_data, Add_Page3_data].transpose().each { execute(w, *it) }` work?

Comment: I'll give it a try. what would transpose do in this instance?

Comment: Whoa, yes, [`transpose()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#transpose-java.util.List-) and then the [spread operator (`*it`) for method arguments](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_spreading_method_arguments), beautiful...